# Saving data types in specific memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, arm, mbed

I'm currently programming the NUCLEO-F103RB in c++. I have run into a problem, the program that i create is always being saved on the SRAM which is only 20KB. My program and the other files exceed 20KB. So i can no longer save it to the embed.

The flash memory on the other hand is 128KB, this is more then enough for what i need. Can someone please tell me how i can save my program onto this flash memory? Will I have to add some lines of code to save it directly there? I currently make my program and then drag and drop the program onto the mbed.
I am writing my program using the online mbed compiler (link at the bottom). 
I've looked through the hand book and it doesn't really answer the question I have.

I have tried to give as much information as possible but if you need more information please ask.

https://developer.mbed.org/compiler/#

Comment: Sorry, this is no tutorial site. How about reading the documentation yourself first. If you don't understand it, you maybe need to learn more about embedded systems development basics.

Comment: @Olaf We meet again olaf. I have stated that i have read the hand book which is recommended read and in that it does not state how to swap memory location. 
Maybe someone on here has experience with this problem and can tell me what steps they took.

Comment: the NUCLEO boards mount as virtual flash drives, you create a .bin file intended to be run at address 0x0000 (has the vector table as the first thing and the entry) and you simply copy the file over, drag and drop with your mouse or cp or copy on the command line whatever your preference is.  then the debug end of the board automatically loads it into the flash of the target microcontroller and resets the microcontroller.  further manual resets or power cycles will run your flash based program.  am quite curious how you are running in sram.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks for your input. I follow exactly those steps that you have said to move my program into the mbed. I know that it is only showing me the sram option on my computer because if you go on the properties for the drive it shows that you have 20KB free which is the memory space for the SRAM. Is there a way to configure the mbed to exclusively work with the flash memory?

Comment: that is how it works, it writes to flash, not ram.  I have not made large binaries for the nucleo boards, so have not run into this so I dont know why it is limiting you.   I just tried a NUCLEO-F401RE  which is 512k/96k and a 128K file worked (put .align 17 in the bootstrap).  next step a little over 256K and it loaded fine.  this is on ubuntu linux, so YMMV.  perhaps the frontend only has so much ram/space as a transfer area for the target mcu...one would expect it to be able to handle the full flash size

Comment: there are firmware upgrades for these nucleo front ends, and I think I upgraded mine at least when I got them.   that may make a difference.  used to just be a windows program but there may have been support for other oses the last time I tried that.  that may help

Comment: http://www2.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/development-tool-software/stsw-link007.html
 maybe it will help

Comment: @dwelch I tried to upgrade it and it still doesn't work. For your NUCLEO-F401RE, when you connect it to the computer and right click the properties button, does it tell you that you have 512K or 96K of memory? I am pretty sure it states that you have 512k of memory which is why you can  write your 256K data. If i am wrong please let me know

Comment: flash is generally larger than the sram in these types of devices.

Comment: /dev/sde              520          8       512   2% /media/dwelch/NUCLEO
520 1k-blocks total  , 8 used, 512 available.

Comment: @dwelch I am kind of confused by your final comment. On your computer did it say you had total of 512KB or 96KB?

Comment: there is 512KBytes of flash, 96Kbytes of ram.  you are saying that your free space shows the ram or you are limited by the ram size.  I demonstrated that I am not limited by the ram size, I can copy a 256Kbyte file, which is greater than 96 and less than 512.

Comment: you say yours is 128/20 I say mine is 512/96.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was something wrong with my board, i just exchanged my board with a new one and it works fine now. It was a faulty board. If someone else is facing this problem just go back to the seller. 
Thanks to all who tried to answer my question